# Sphinx search with xml pipe

Tags: sphinx

I have one json array of Objects.I am creating sphinx compatible xml document from this JSON Array.For each object i create one document and specify id value for it.For example if json array contains 20 objects then i have to create 20 documents starting from 1 to 20.Now my json  array update with time and new Objects come in place so i need to assign them id starting from 21 and so on.So is there any way to maintain this id values from Sphinx side internally?

Answer (score 0):

Just store the latest used id somewhere. A text file or something.

Or just get the highest id from the sphinx index. So the script building the xml file, could just first run a sphinxql query

```
select id from gi_stemmed order by id desc limit 1;
```